# Cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons' to 'string'

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

> Cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons' to 'string'

Which I had no idea for

```
MessageBox.Show("Problem generating the quiz.Sorry!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error

Random rdmNumber = new Random();
number1 = rdmNumber.Next(0, 10);
number2 = rdmNumber.Next(0, 10);
int selectOp = rdmNumber.Next(0, 4);
operation = "";
switch (selectOp)
{
    case 1:
        operation = " + ";
        solution = number1 + number2;
        break;
    case 2:
        operation = " - ";
        if (number1 < number2)
        {
            int temp = number1;
            number1 = number2;
            number2 = temp;
        }
        solution = number1 - number2;
        break;
    case 3:
        operation = " x ";
        solution = number1 * number2;
        break;
    case 4:
        operation = " % "; // take out the extra equal sign
        solution = number1 % number2;
        break;
    default:
        MessageBox.Show("Problem generating the quiz.Sorry!", 
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        break;
}
```

Comment: You need to enter the mbox title before the button and after the message...

Answer (score 6):

You're missing the caption element of the `MessageBox`

```
MessageBox.Show("Problem generating the quiz.Sorry!", "Caption",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

[The documentation:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/365dky5y(v=vs.110).aspx)

> MessageBox.Show Method (String, String, MessageBoxButtons, MessageBoxIcon)

Comment: See docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0x49kd7z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Jérôme Thanks was about to add it.

Comment: Thank you so much I was stuck at that part. But, It's hard for beginners like me.

Comment: @Vincent It's okay we all have to start somewhere. I'm happy I could help :)